# Enabling Cache in Jasper Server

Tags: jasperserver, rest

I am having a few reports in Jasper Server. I am accessing the reports on another server using rest-api for Jasper. The report is loaded there successfully.
**My Problem**
The report fetches data from the database every time and fills it. When there is too much data, it takes a lot of time to build and fill the report.
**What I want to do?**
I want to know whether there is any kind of cache option in Jasper Server which downloads the report image to the server for the first time when it is loaded for the first time. When it is loaded for the second time, it should load the downloaded report rather than fetching the data and loading the report again. Is there any option for this in Jasper?

**Update**
Can the adHoc cache be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If you for example converted the image to a BufferedImage and pass it in as a parameter, you have to option to set

```
isUsingCache = true
```

for these elements. This will load them from the cache rather than fetching them again. For this to work you will have to configure a cache on your Jasper Server.

To cache report jobs and OLAP connections see [here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ehcache-learning-more) and for querys see your mentioned adhoc cache [here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/configuring-ad-hoc-cache).

Comment: what image are you talking about ?

Comment: I am using rest api to get data. would that work for rest api?

Comment: This is something I don't know but I assume yes. Try it and give me feedback. If not, I'll try to help you.

Comment: if you could explain more a bit